# The Eureka Server has become unavailable, version is 3.1.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix

My `application.yml` is :

```yaml
server:
  port: 9700

spring:
  application:
    name: SERVER-ALPHA

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: SERVER-ALPHA
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://172.22.58.174:9800/eureka/
    enabled: true
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    renewal-percent-threshold: 0.85
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
    use-read-only-response-cache: false
    response-cache-update-interval-ms: 1000
```

The anothor one is:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9800

spring:
  application:
    name: SERVER-BETA

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: SERVER-BETA
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://172.22.58.174:9700/eureka/
    enabled: true
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    renewal-percent-threshold: 0.85
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
    use-read-only-response-cache: false
    response-cache-update-interval-ms: 1000
```

And The Page of eureka is:
[image]

and I can't use the server to do the discovery.

the version is:
[image]

How to resolve this problem?

thx

First I try to use the `eureka.client.enable` is true, but I found that the default value is true.
So I try to find the answer but I found the most of them the spring cloud version is below 2021, I use the spring boot 2.6.7 or 2.6.13, so I didn't find the resolve way.

Comment: Can you describe what is happening exactly? Log errors? Client errors?